# Un programa en C que de una lista de numeros primos, no primos y divisibles

Tags: c

Hola he estado intentado hacer que mi programa me imprima el resultado de los números primos los no primos y a la vez por 2 y por 3 los divisibles.
Pero no lo he conseguido por ejemplo mi código es capaz de imprimir un solo numero y decir si es primo o no primo pero aun no he conseguido que me de la lista de los primos los no primos y los divisibles al escribir un rango de números.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
  int n, i, flag = 0;
  printf("Ingrese un número entero positivo: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (flag == 0) {
    printf("%d es un numero primo.", n);
  } 
  else {
    
      printf("%d no es un número primo.", n);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

El programa al ejecutar por ejemplo una lista de numeros como este:
**23 55 12 44 11 66 344 2 4 9**
Deberia imprimir el resultado algo parecido a esto:

```
PRIMOS: 23 11 2
NO PRIMOS: 55 12 44 66 344 4 9
DIVISIBLES por 2 y 3: 12 66
```

Agradezco de antemano toda la ayuda que se me pueda aportar.

Comment: Como recomendación, rompe en problema en partes más pequeñas. En tu caso, por un lado podes verificar si un número es primo y por otro ir verificando cada número en un arreglo, cuáles son primos o no. Cada procedimiento puede estar en una función para reutilizar y ahorrar código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes tres preguntas a responder frente a un número:

- ¿Es primo?
- ¿Es divisible entre tres?
- ¿Es divisible entre dos?

Haz funciones que respondan a cada una de las preguntas:

```
#define FLAG_DIV_2 1
#define FLAG_DIV_3 2
#define FLAG_PRIMO 4

int divisible_2(int numero)
{
    return numero % 2 ? 0 : FLAG_DIV_2;
}

int divisible_3(int numero)
{
    return numero % 3 ? 0 : FLAG_DIV_3;
}

int es_primo(int numero)
{
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= numero / 2; ++divisor)
        if (numero % divisor == 0)
            return 0;

    return FLAG_PRIMO;
}
```

Después, puedes interrogar cada una de las funciones para preguntar sobre cada número, si haces un listado que guarde los resultados puedes usarlo para imprimir lo que pides:

```
int numeros[10] = {23, 55, 12, 44, 11, 66, 344, 2, 4, 9};
int resultados[10] = {};

for (int indice = 0; indice != 10; ++indice)
{
    if (!(resultados[indice] = divisible_2(numeros[indice]) | divisible_3(numeros[indice])))
        resultados[indice] = es_primo(numeros[indice]);
}

printf("PRIMOS: ");
for (int indice = 0; indice != 10; ++indice)
    if (resultados[indice] & FLAG_PRIMO)
        printf("%d ", numeros[indice]);

printf("\nNO PRIMOS: ");
for (int indice = 0; indice != 10; ++indice)
    if (!(resultados[indice] & FLAG_PRIMO))
        printf("%d ", numeros[indice]); 

printf("\nDIVISIBLES por 2 y 3: ");
for (int indice = 0; indice != 10; ++indice)
    if ((resultados[indice] & FLAG_DIV_3) && (resultados[indice] & FLAG_DIV_2))
        printf("%d ", numeros[indice]);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZNvT8IwEMZfr5/igEi2MHXrgETGNBr/hATFSOIbNQRZ0SajkG2YGOSzz3Zs3RhEUF9td8/uud9d19HhyBuytyiqUDby5i6BdhC6dHr0fopQxSVjyghcd89vBpedxwEGczNpAV5P3j90bntQR4iyEFz6QQP66pEBVkXM5hPiTzW0QIpPwrnPkgwcAIYzMKCVa2ejZdHF2uViFV0s6UKCwcynk2nRYjz1QZVteOAAtmXQdlLzY5Gu1RJBQ4pCx6DKzrLaAUOIKZphI4mZLUhSTYaUqTFHhhU8mcYLx1hgS4dGQwcT61Cv86epQ7OpgyUCkdPhZGmvSn0SzL1w6GbVS9FZTkeZS0eE5w07fS85YBpiplXMqRfJVCU1Z7dShWX@OFPURNXga@2cirKW7GSLqzyYYg2fjG9J4SILx2o5Xly/BWUh/G6ueKgtzau5I4kB014HLpR12ATKaJ7ZXQ/@i1TaCbUPlbKGxf/6Tr9z0b3qw4wTYfgE6@@EPwDG10uDahV2fIS1PXebXZllFH0D)</kbd>.

Comment: Hola probé tu código y al parecer funciona bien pero al parecer como no es escrito en lenguaje maquina no me compila de la manera correcta.

Comment: Si querías una respuesta en lenguaje máquina, no deberías etiquetar tu pregunta como [tag:c].

Comment: Si eso me di cuenta ya solucione poniendo todo antes del int main

Comment: Por cierto estuve viendo y al parecer en el programa sale como el 2 no es un numero primo cuando realmente si lo es intente arreglando los flagdiv para ver si lograba solucionarlo pero luego de eso me salia que el 9 no es primo y a la vez es divisible asi que estoy intentando ver como solucionarlo @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: @AbdulrahimOmais copié tu algoritmo de detección de primos tal cual, cambiando los nombres de las variables, deberías revisarlo.