# Error de compilación en algunos IDE del lenguaje C

Tags: c++, c

Hola a todos necesito ayuda para saber como solucionar este error de compilación en el lenguaje C el cual en algunos IDE como dev c++ ejecuta de manera satisfactoria pero en otros me de errores tales como estos:

```
LAB2-1.c: In function ‘int primosdiv23(long int*)’:
LAB2-1.c:31:25: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  int divisible2(numero) { return numero % 2 ? 0 : FLAGDIV2; }
                         ^
LAB2-1.c:33:25: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  int divisible3(numero) { return numero % 3 ? 0 : FLAGDIV3; }
                         ^
LAB2-1.c:36:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
LAB2-1.c:47:47: error: ‘divisible2’ cannot be used as a function
     if (!(resultados[i] = divisible2(vector[i]) | divisible3(vector[i])))
                                               ^
LAB2-1.c:47:71: error: ‘divisible3’ cannot be used as a function
     if (!(resultados[i] = divisible2(vector[i]) | divisible3(vector[i])))
                                                                       ^
LAB2-1.c:48:42: error: ‘esprimo’ cannot be used as a function
         resultados[i] = esprimo(vector[i]);
                                          ^
LAB2-1.c:54:32: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%d ", vector[i]);
                       ~~~~~~~~~^
LAB2-1.c:59:32: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%d ", vector[i]); 
                       ~~~~~~~~~^
LAB2-1.c:64:32: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%d ", vector[i]);
                       ~~~~~~~~~^
```

Intente solucionarlo de mucha formas pero todas siempre me ha dado fallas ya que con el IDE que se me ha indicado utilizar el cual es Codegrade no es muy complejo no es capaz de ejecutar el código de manera correcta  les dejo el código para que lo prueben y sean capaz de comprender por los errores que mi código esta pasando por favor tomar en cuenta que este codigo funciona bajo los comandos argv y argc para sacar los numeros primos si desean utilizen estos parametros para que se pueda testear mi codigo:
**23 55 12 44 11 66 344 2 4 9** adicional a eso les dejo el codigo que he creado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define FLAGDIV2  1
#define FLAGDIV3  2
#define FLAGPRIMO 4
void div23(long vector[]);
int  primosdiv23(long vector[]);
int  esprimo(int numero);
long vector[10];
int  main(int argc, char *argv[]) { // función principal
    int   i = 0;
    char *p;
    if (argc != 11) {
        printf("DEBE INTRODUCIR 10 ARGUMENTOS ENTEROS...\n");
        return (0);
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { // bucle transformar argumentos en enteros
        vector[i - 1] = strtol(argv[i], &p, 10);
    }
    primosdiv23(vector);
    return (0);
}

int primosdiv23(long vector[]) {

    int numero, divisor, i, resultados[10];

    int divisible2(numero) {
        return numero % 2 ? 0 : FLAGDIV2;
    }
    int divisible3(numero) {
        return numero % 3 ? 0 : FLAGDIV3;
    }
    int esprimo(numero) {
        for (divisor = 2; divisor <= numero / 2; ++divisor)
            if (numero % divisor == 0)
                return 0;
        return FLAGPRIMO;
    }
    for (i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
        if (!(resultados[i] = divisible2(vector[i]) | divisible3(vector[i])))
            resultados[i] = esprimo(vector[i]);
    }
    printf("PRIMOS: ");
    for (i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        if (resultados[i] & FLAGPRIMO)
            printf("%d ", vector[i]);
    printf("\nNO PRIMOS: ");
    for (i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        if (!(resultados[i] & FLAGPRIMO))
            printf("%d ", vector[i]);
    printf("\nDIVISIBLES por 2 y 3: ");
    for (i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        if ((resultados[i] & FLAGDIV3) && (resultados[i] & FLAGDIV2))
            printf("%d ", vector[i]);
    return (0);
}
```

Agradezco de antemano todas las respuestas que se me pueda ofrecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leer los errores te ayudará a comprender que está pasando.

> In function ‘int primosdiv23(long int*)’:

Te está indicando que en la función `primosdiv23` hay algunos errores. En 3 ocasiones esperaba una coma o un punto y coma pero ninguna fue escrita.

Esto en realidad te sucede porque no puedes definir una función dentro de otra. Entonces el compilador lo interpreta como si estuvieras queriendo declarar una variable. Por esta misma razón estás teniendo los siguientes 3 errores que te dicen que `divisible2`, `divisible3` y `esprimo` no pueden usarse como funciones.

La mayoría de errores los tuviste al copiar el código de [la respuesta a otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/505897/169744) que hiciste. Que por cierto, funciona bien. No hay nada malo en él.

Si quieres ver cómo queda todo unido en un programa, el otro miembro te dejó un botón al final de su respuesta dónde puedes hacerlo y probar el código.

En cuanto al último error, `%d` es para imprimir un int. En cambio, para un `long` debes usar `%ld`.

Así:

```
 long numero = 10;
 printf ("%ld", numero);
```

Puedes ver otras posibilidades en [esta página](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por el consejo ya lo solucione movi las variables divisibles 2 y 3 y esprimo asi  logre hacer que leyera mi codigo. pero me acaba de enterar que el 2 es un numero primo y ahora estoy viendo como hacer que considere el 2 como numero primo

Comment: Puedes agregar una condición de modo que si el número es 2 te devuelva lo que esperas. Algunas optimizaciones para el algoritmo de números primos consisten en ver si el número es 2, 3 o sociable por 2 y sino comenzar a probar divisores de 2 en 2, comenzando por el 3 hasta las raíz cuadrada del número que quieres saber si es primo.

Comment: intente arreglando los flagdiv pero resulta salirme que el 9 es divisible y a la vez no primo estoy intentando cambiando los valores.

Comment: Está bien, el 9 no es primo ya que es divisible por 3. Como recomendación, haz que las funciones `divisible2`, `divisible3` y `esprimo` devuelvan un bool `true` o `false` en lugar de un entero.